# python2.7 Save console log in file

Tags: python-2.7

I need help how to write output in python 2.7
python code.py >> output.txt not suitable because it does not display data while the script is running.

Comment: `python code.py | tee -a output.txt` ?

Comment: Error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JNNrsjT2ht/

Comment: Might be worth bringing in the paste bin into your current question. Means people who are able to answer the question don't need to context switch.

You can surround on both sides with ` characters to nicely format it.

Comment: Ok. Next time I will use.